# How to show 6 instead of 3 slides for slideshow using a plugin

Tags: jquery, asp.net

How can I show more 3 slides ( =6) for [slide show](http://www.jquerytools.org/demos/tabs/slideshow.html) plugin for the tabs? The default setting gives me only 3 slides, but I need 6.

My Codes is:

```
$(function () {

        $(".slidetabs").tabs(".images > div", {

            // enable "cross-fading" effect
            effect: 'fade',
            fadeOutSpeed: "slow",

            // start from the beginning after the last tab
            rotate: true,


            // use the slideshow plugin. It accepts its own configuration
        }).slideshow({ clickable: false });
    });
```

Thanks.

Comment: ok.i cant good learning english

Comment: then how do you expect to understand code?

Comment: @Hoorakhsh Could you explain in a bit more words what you want to do and what not? Maybe we can figure it out step by step to get a clear question?

Comment: thanks @Shegit Brahm
i find is solution.
should added more <a href=""></a> tag main jquery code.
            <div class="slidetabs">
                <a href=""></a><a href=""></a><a href=""></a><a href=""></a><a href=""></a>
            </div>
I'm sorry to all for the concept of question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly what you want is to be able to show 6 slides instead of the 3 that the plugin shows as standard.

If thats a case its a simple HTML change.

The code is currently as follows:

```
   <!-- container for the slides -->
   <div class="images">

     <!-- first slide -->
     <div>Lorem ipsum ..</div>

      <!-- second slide -->
     <div>Lorem ipsum ..</div>

     <!-- third slide -->
     <div>Lorem ipsum ..</div>

    </div>
```

You simply need to change it too the following:

```
     <!-- first slide -->
     <div>Lorem ipsum ..</div>

      <!-- second slide -->
     <div>Lorem ipsum ..</div>

     <!-- third slide -->
     <div>Lorem ipsum ..</div>

     <!-- fourth slide -->
     <div>Lorem ipsum ..</div>

      <!-- fifth slide -->
     <div>Lorem ipsum ..</div>

     <!-- sixth slide -->
     <div>Lorem ipsum ..</div>

    </div>
```

You would also need to add three more a hrefs:

```
    <div class="slidetabs">
       <a href="#"></a>
       <a href="#"></a>
       <a href="#"></a>
       <a href="#"></a>
       <a href="#"></a>
       <a href="#"></a>
    </div>
```

Hope this helps.